# Firefox render bug with fixed background images and a filter applied

Tags: firefox, rendering, gecko

So I was experimenting with css `filter`, the experiment worked quite well but not in Firefox.

I wanted to apply a filter onto a segment of the background image. The idea was to fix the background image of the wrapper and the inner elements to create the illusion that the filter is applying only to a certain area and can be moved, here with scrolling.

This is what I tried:

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 200%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column
}

body,
div {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/wu7EkAX.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

div {
    filter: saturate(0%);
    width: 50%;
    height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

This works quite well with Chrome (and I think also in other browsers) but not with Firefox. It seems like it is a result of some optimization which misbehaves.

If you scroll with your mousewheele and then click, it refreshes, otherwise it stays in this state (at least if you run it standalone).

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" is quite simple, you force Firefox to re render, there are whole posts about this topic but here are two of my approaches:

With a css animation

```
@keyframes renderFix {
    from {
        outline-color: red;
    }

    to {
        outline-color: blue;
    }
}

html {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    animation: 1s infinite alternate renderFix;
}
```

With some JavaScript

```
{
    let html, s = false,
        cycle = function () {
            html.style.outlineColor = s ? "red" : "blue"
            s = !s;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(cycle)
        }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        html = document.body.parentElement
        html.style.outlineStyle = "solid";
        html.style.outlineWidth = "1px";
        cycle()
    })
}
```

The JavaScript fix applied:

```js
{
    let html, s = false,
        cycle = function () {
            html.style.outlineColor = s ? "red" : "blue"
            s = !s;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(cycle)
        }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        html = document.body.parentElement
        html.style.outlineStyle = "solid";
        html.style.outlineWidth = "1px";
        cycle()
    })
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 200%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column
}

body,
div {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/wu7EkAX.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

div {
    filter: saturate(0%);
    width: 50%;
    height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```